# Is it safe to implement elliptic curve Diffie Hellman with secp256k1

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, signal-protocol, x25519, secp256k1

I need to implement X3DH Key Agreement Protocol according to [Signal specification](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/#ref-rfc7748), in the document they suggest using either X25519 or X448 curves. I assume those curves have been chosen for this protocol for a reason. In the codebase elliptic curve public key cryptosystem has already been implemented with secp256k1. Would it be safe to generate the keys needed for this protocol using the existing implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Although mathematically Koblitz curves are a few bits weaker than random curves, in a context of elliptic curve cryptography of 256+ bits, those differences are innocuous, I would say, it's safe.

X25519 curves are fast, but not as secure as P-256, I think you are in a good track,

Best regards

Comment: https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/index.html would disagree that P-256 is a better choice.

Comment: In first instance maybe is "ok" to check safecurves.cr, but yet, we need Cryptographic analysis to determine security, based on algorithm breaks or mathematical theory, Curve25519 is faster, not safer than P-256, X25519 is just DH with Curve25519, excellent choice for experimental purposes, bad choice if people just look up at safeCurves.cr and play the NIST conspiracy game. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519 https://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/68653

Comment: I can see how the argument can be made that P-256 is as secure as Curve25519. Please could you substantiate your claim that Curve25519 is not as secure as P-256 .

Comment: Curve25519 is secure, not widely supported as P-256 although that could change because is getting very popular, for now, I always stick to the most-tested-used curves to determine security if we deal with financial industry, that's why I prefer P-256, aside from controversial claims of intentional backdoors.

Comment: P-256 is popular since it is in the NIST list. NIST suggests 25519 for ECDSA with Edwards25519.

Comment: @kelalaka: the prime subgroup in P-256 is about $2^{256}$, which leads to about '128 bit security' against discrete log attacks.  The prime subgroup in Curve25519 is about $2^{252}$, which leads to about '126 bit security' against discrete log attacks.  128 > 126...

Comment: @knaccc: oops; my last comment (about why Curve25519 is slightly weaker than P-256) was supposed to be addressed to you